# Quebra de linhas no colnames ou rownames

Tags: r

esse é um exemplo de um relatório que estou fazendo. Como as configurações de margem já estão ajustadas, quando mudo os nomes das colunas com o colnames ele acaba passando a margem. Algum help de como quebrar essa linha ? Por exemplo do "Previsto ARIMA". Vai uma imagem de como poderia ficar. [image: Exemplo]

```
x <- runif(n = 15, min = 1, 10)
y <- runif(n = 15, min = 1, 10)
z <- runif(n = 15, min = 1, 10)
w <- runif(n = 15, min = 1, 10)
k <- runif(n = 15, min = 1, 10)


df_exemplo <- data.frame(x, y, z, w, k)
colnames(df_exemplo) <- c("Previsto ARIMA", "Previsto Holtwinters", "Observado", "Erro ARIMA (%)", "Erro Holtwinters (%)")
```

Comment: Isto é uma pergunta de Excel?

Comment: @RuiBarradas apenas o exemplo é em Excel pra mostrar como eu queria mostrasse no PDF, esqueci de comentar que isso é um relatório em Sweave. Se tem algum jeito de quebrar essa linha diretamente pelo R, já tentei usar o "\n" mas não nã funfa também.

Comment: @RafaelB, onde o texto vai aparecer? Se for em um gráfico, por exemplo, a quebra de linha com `"\n"` funciona tanto no `r-base` quanto no `ggplot2`

Comment: @TomásBarcellos o texto vai aparecer no nome de uma coluna (colnames) de uma tabela.

Comment: Se for apenas para uso interativo, `View(df_exemplo)` já quebra as linhas mesmo sem introduzir nenhum `"\n"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu recomendo utilizar o pacote `kableExtra` para formatar tabelas no `knitr` ou `sweave`. Ele trabalha em conjunto com a função `kable` do pacote `knitr` e os resultados são muito bacanas. Veja abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código utilizado para criar esta tabela:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

<<Dados>>=
x <- runif(n = 15, min = 1, 10)
y <- runif(n = 15, min = 1, 10)
z <- runif(n = 15, min = 1, 10)
w <- runif(n = 15, min = 1, 10)
k <- runif(n = 15, min = 1, 10)

df_exemplo <- data.frame(x, y, z, w, k)
colnames(df_exemplo) <- c("Previsto ARIMA", "Previsto Holtwinters", 
                          "Observado", "Erro ARIMA (%)", 
                          "Erro Holtwinters (%)")
@


<<TabelaComQuebra, warning=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

kable(df_exemplo, "latex", booktabs=TRUE, digits=4) %>%
  column_spec(1:5, width = c("1.5cm", "2cm", "2cm", "2cm", "2.5cm"))
@


\end{document}
```

Note que tive que carregar dois pacotes do LaTeX para que a tabela saísse neste formato. A quebra de linha no título da tabela saiu automaticamente ao utilizar a função `column_spec`. Eu apenas defini a largura que eu gostaria que a coluna tivesse e o software fez o restante.

Comment: Warning message:
In table_info$align_vector[column] <- unlist(lapply(table_info$align_vector_origin[column],  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Tentei mudar a sequência no "column_spec" e adicionar uma coluna a mais ou tirar uma coluna, entretanto não deu certo.

Comment: Estava certo mesmo, estava usando em outra tabela.

Comment: Big thanks, Marcus. Migrarei do xtable pro kable, a partir de agora.

Comment: kable rainha, xtable nadinha : )